# Recursively download a package's dependencies with yum?

Tags: linux, fedora, raspberry-pi

Is there a way I can use `yum` to check all of a package's dependencies and grab those first, then check their dependencies...so I can get the package I want in one swoop?

Comment: AFAIK, `yum install` already does this.

Comment: When I tried to install `gnome-panel` it said there were 6-10 dependencies. But...I'm an idiot so there's always that :)

Comment: It should always list the dependencies, but then fetch everything in one go, check everything, and then install in some sensible order.